# How to use the same entity field in many entities?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

What is the best way to have the same entity field in many entities?
For example an 'relatedEntity' will be appearing in 8 tables.

```
class User
{
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
        private ?string $relatedEntity = null;
}
```

```
class User2
{
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
        private ?string $relatedEntity = null;
}
```

RelatedEntity in 'User' is like a parent field for others. Is it any way to map them between each other to make querying simpler?

I've tried OneToOne but everytime it adds a new user and I don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, you could use a [Trait](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) or use an [abstract class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Like @LBA said in his answer, if your entities share many things in common and only have a few differences you may want to look into [inheritance mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

Trait example:

```php
trait RelatedEntityTrait
{
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $relatedEntity = null;

    public function getRelatedEntity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->relatedEntity;
    }

    public function setRelatedEntity(?string $relatedEntity): void
    {
        $this->relatedEntity = $relatedEntity;
    }
}

class User
{
    use RelatedEntityTrait;
}

class User2
{
    use RelatedEntityTrait;
}
```

Abstract class example:

```php
abstract class BaseUser
{
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $relatedEntity = null;

    public function getRelatedEntity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->relatedEntity;
    }

    public function setRelatedEntity(?string $relatedEntity): void
    {
        $this->relatedEntity = $relatedEntity;
    }
}

class User extends BaseUser
{
}

class User2 extends BaseUser
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole world around this and several approaches.

- MappedSuperclass
- Entity Inheritance
- Single and Class Table Inheritance
  all are supported by Doctrine, read [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping)

Another option would be to use

- Traits

like some common Doctrine Extensions are doing it, please find some approach documented [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-traits-doctrine-entities/)

Not knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve it's hard to recommend one or other.

Please come back with more detailed questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain. User have an useruuid field, and other entities got the same useruuid field - just to know which user filled which form.

Every form got own entity - the rest of app requires that.

So, how can i join every entity 'uuid' with parent 'user - uuid'?

It's all about efficiency with query to get all of user filled forms. Now it left joining every entity and check if uuid is matching.